# 404 ошибка на несуществующую страницу пагинации

Tags: wordpress, wp-plugin

Есть сайт на движке WordPress.

Если открыть страницу в блоге, например, с url таким: `mysite.com/blog/super-post/`

А затем переидти на вторую страницу (которой у поста нет) по адресу: `mysite.com/blog/super-post/2/`, то 404-я ошибка не будет отдана.

То же самое будет и на этой странице: `mysite.com/blog/super-post/232323/`.

Я так понимаю, что WordPress ищет максимально схожую (или близкую) страницу.

Но мне хочется, чтобы все ссылки были жесткими и 404-я ошибка отдавалась на подобные запросы.

Подскажите, каким образом это можно поправить? Настройками, плагином, какими-нибудь хуками?

Comment: Пробывали обновлять пермалинки и сбрасывать правила реврайтов ?

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, каким образом это можно поправить? Настройками, плагином,
>   какими-нибудь хуками?

Поправить никак (без серьёзного влезания в пермалинки), но можно запретить индексацию пагинации в СЕО плагинах. Или же построить ЧПУ/слаги так, чтобы было можно было составить простое правило редиректа.